# According to "New chrome policy" we cant play an audio without user interaction

Tags: angular, google-chrome, notifications, policy

Is there any alternative to avoid this issue? Probably a button simulation or whatever.

> .ts file

```
  var soundBlock = new Howl({
  src: ['./../../../assets/audios/drughi.wav'],
  autoplay: true,

});



  else if(msg.infusionStatus == 'Blocked'){
       this.dripos.forEach(function (dripo,index) {
           if(msg._id == dripo._id){

             dripo.status='alerted';
             dripo.infusionStatus='Blocked';


           }

           soundBlock.play(); 

       });
```

Comment: Problem is solved by changing site settings .Allowed trusted site,  allowed adds, allowed  audio for the specific site.